# Updating view by calling Action Method from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a javacript Like this:

```
<script>
    function GetFromDate() {    
        var dt1 = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
        var dt2 = document.getElementById('toDate').value;
        var url = "Statistics/Excel/"  + dt1 + "!" + dt2;        
        window.location.href = url;
        return false;

    };
</script>
```

and in controller my ActionResult is like this:

```
 public ActionResult Excel(string id)
        {
              \\ View Creation
               if(SomeLogic)
                  {
                         \\Excel Download Options
                  }
          return View(viewModel);
       }
```

Though it is perfectly working with the Excel Downloading option but it is not returning the View. Any Suggestions?
For more information "viewModel" object contains the perfect data to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If your response is returning a file download, then this counts as your Http response, you aren't able to then do a redirect in the same action.

Comment: Then what could be the right method to do? What I am trying to do is to render the view depending upon the date range selected...I have heard of partial view in MVC...is there any way to do this with partial view?